# Source Forge repo gives "denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/master" error

Tags: git, version-control

I [rewrote the tree to my git repository to fix errors in the author name and email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-do-i-change-the-author-of-a-commit-in-git). Now I'm trying to push the fixed tree to my repo on Source Forge. [CharlesB told me how to update the config file on the Source Forge servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449230/moving-remote-branch/12449278#12449278). My config file looks like this:

```
[codeguru@shell-24003 bbct]$ cat config
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = true
        sharedrepository = 2
[receive]
        denyNonFastforwards = false
```

Now when I try to force a push, I get the following error:

```
$ git push -f
Password:
Counting objects: 464, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (148/148), done.
Writing objects: 100% (452/452), 470.65 KiB, done.
Total 452 (delta 268), reused 417 (delta 247)
remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/master (you should pull first)
To ssh://codeguru@git.code.sf.net/p/bbct/code
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://codeguru@git.code.sf.net/p/bbct/code'
```

What's going on here? More importantly, how do I fix it?

**Update:**

Running `git push -f` on a public campus computer gives the same error message as above.

**Another Update:**

I cloned the SF repo to a temporary folder, reset this temporary repo's master branch to the commit just before the first commit with the wrong author and email, then ran `git push -f`. I get the exact same error message as with my original repo:

```
$ git push -f
Password:
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/master (you should pull first)
To ssh://codeguru@git.code.sf.net/p/bbct/code
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://codeguru@git.code.sf.net/p/bbct/code'
```

I guess SF really doesn't want me doing a non-fast-forward commit here :-(

Comment: so it's the same error as your previous question?

Comment: Yes, it appears so. Other than right now I don't get the "permission denied" error. I'm on a different machine now, too.

Comment: so on the original machine `push -f` works, and not on this one?

Comment: @CharlesB `git push -f` doesn't work on either machine. The most recent errors on the other machine are in the "Update" section of at the bottom of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449230/moving-remote-branch/12449278

Comment: @CharlesB Yes, the difference is the other machine (the public one) gives a "permission denied" error.

Comment: @CharlesB Sorry, I was having difficulty using the chat feature on my buddy's computer. If you are still on, I can chat with you now.

Comment: Here are detailed instructions to resolve this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43721579/2073804

Comment: @ron190 Thanks for the link. Hopefully it will help future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this was in fact a SourceForge issue, and perhaps a user error as well. In the SF shell, I originally edited the config file for my project under the `/home/scm_git` directory. After submitting a ticket to SF, I found out that the correct directory is `/home/git` instead. After editing the config file in the correct subdirectory for my project, I forced a push and updated the master branch successfully.

Answer (score 17):

It could be a simple matter of case:

```
[receive]
        denyNonFastForwards = false
```

Note the uppercase '`F`' for '`Forwards`'.
So fix your config file on the Source Forge servers, and your `git push -f` should succeed, from any workstation.

Comment: ooo...thanks for pointing that out. I don't remember editing the variable name, but I'll double check that.

Comment: Well, I tried it and still get the same error message. I submitted a ticket to SF support. Hopefully I'll hear something back from them soon.