# Force Git push on SourceForge

Tags: git, version-control, git-push, sourceforge

I'm trying to rollback a Git repository on SourceForge. I tried the following:

```
git reset --hard 9ac2e31ca4a155d4c36780b4329626045a7f40ed
HEAD ist jetzt bei 9ac2e31 Fix warnings


git push -f origin master
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/master (you should pull first)
To ssh://user@git.code.sf.net/p/project/code
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: Fehler beim Versenden einiger Referenzen nach 'ssh://user@git.code.sf.net/p/project/code'
```

How can I override the `master` branch for a remote SourceForge Git repository?

Comment: Do you have the property denyNonFastforwards set as false in the config file, by any chance?

Comment: Maybe. I don't know. I found an [issue on SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/site-support/9558/) about this problem.

Comment: You may be able to delete the remote branch and then push master as a completely new branhc.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I already tried to delete the remote master branch, but this does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Source Forge repo gives "denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/master" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450703/source-forge-repo-gives-denying-non-fast-forward-refs-heads-master-error)

Answer (score 6):

Here are detailed instructions to connect to your Sourceforge account and change the `config` file and enable `non-fast-forward` updates.

You can change `denyNonFastForwards` of a standard Sourceforge project from your computer with the following commands :

- Connect to your SSH account using Interactive Shell with command `ssh -t ron190ron190@shell.sourceforge.net create`. Notice that the URL is different from the one of your project:

```bash
$ ssh -t ron190ron190@shell.sourceforge.net create
The authenticity of host 'shell.sourceforge.net (ip)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:key
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'shell.sourceforge.net,ip' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Password:
Requesting a new shell for "user" and waiting for it to start.
queued... creating... starting...
This is an interactive shell created for user user,users
Use the "timeleft" command to see how much time remains before shutdown.
Use the "shutdown" command to destroy the shell before the time limit.
For path information and login help, type "sf-help".
```

- Find the file `config` using `sf-help --scm` or `pwd`, it should be located in folder `/home/git/p/myproject/code.git/`.
- Read the `config` file to check `denyNonFastforwards` status, it is indeed set to true:

```bash
[user@shell-22003 code.git]$ cat config
    [core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = true
        sharedrepository = 2
    [receive]
        denyNonFastforwards = true
```

- Start vi to modify the file, change `true` to `false`:

```bash
[user@shell-22003 code.git]$ vi config
    [core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = true
        sharedrepository = 2
    [receive]
        denyNonFastforwards = false
    ~
    ~
                            1,1           All
```

- Type `:w` to save the change and `:q` to exit vi.

The error `denying non-fast-forward` should not appear anymore.

Comment: ... or instead of `vi`, just use `sed -i 's/denyNonFastforwards = true/denyNonFastforwards = false/' /home/git/p/some_project_name/code.git/config`

Answer (score 5):

Since `denyNonFastforwards`  is a server-side config, you need to access to your repo on the SourceForge side somehow.

As your [ticket mentions](http://sourceforge.net/p/forge/site-support/9558/), this is done with an [interactive shell service](http://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/Shell%20Service/), but that supposes you can use ssh to open a secure shell.

> Running "`sf-help --scm`" in the shell will show you your repo paths.
>   Just tweak the `denyNonFastforwards = true` to `false` for a bit, do your push, and then set it back to `true` (for safety).

However, a message like "`ssh: connect to host shell.sourceforge.net port 22: Connection refused`" could mean that:

- It could be blocked on the client side (check if you can ssh to other services, like GitHub, even though it won't be an *interactive* session)
- or it could be the result of an outage on SourceForge side (but their [status page doesn't report any recent incident](http://sourceforge.net/blog/category/sitestatus/))

Double-check the [SourceForge SSH documentation](http://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/SSH/).

Comment: @LimitedAtonement That is possible, I am not familiar how sourceforge would handle that on its side (now or 4 years ago)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a one-time thing (or not frequent), you can simply delete the remote branch with `git push -d sf branch` and the push.